# Escape sequence in regex parsed by Pattern.LITERAL

Tags: java, regex

Given the following snippet:

```
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\ndog", Pattern.LITERAL);
Matcher mc = pt.matcher("\ndogDoG");
while(mc.find())
{

    System.out.printf("I have found %s starting at the " +
            "index %s and ending at the index    %s%n",mc.group(),mc.start(),mc.end());

}
```

The output will be:

```
I have found 
dog starting at the index 0 and ending at the index 4.
```

It means that even though I have specified `Pattern.LITERAL` which this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html) says that:

> Pattern.LITERAL Enables literal parsing of the pattern. When this flag
>   is specified then the input string that specifies the pattern is
>   treated as a sequence of literal characters. Metacharacters or escape
>   sequences in the input sequence will be given no special meaning.

However the output given from the above snippet does interpret the `\n` escape sequence, it does not treat it like a literal.

Why does it happen in that way since they specify in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html) tutorial that it should not?

I now \n is a line terminator, however it's still an escape sequence character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pattern.LITERAL` cares about *regex literals*, not *string literals*.

Therefore, it treats `\\n` as `backslash` plus `n` (instead of the regex token for newline), but it treats `\n` as the line feed character that it stands for (and thus ignores it).

Answer (score 2):

> however it's still an escape sequence character.

No it's not. It's a newline character. You can do:

```
char c = '\n';
```

Your output is therefore expected.

Note that if you compile a pattern with:

```
Pattern.compile("\n")
```

then `\n` is the literal character `\n`.

BUT if you compile with:

```
Pattern.compile("\\n")
```

*then* it is an escape sequence. And they happen to match the same thing.